# system reliability on-off switches

Tags: probability

Trying to understand if my solution is correct.
A,C,H are called "terminals" - they are always on.
I am looking for the probability that only 2 terminals are connected, assuming F is always down. Probability for any vertix to be on is p.

I divided it into 3 cases: "AC", "CH", "AH".

P(AC) = 1/3 (B or BE) = 1/3 * (p + p*p)

P(CH) = 1/3 (D or DG) = 1/3 * (p + p*p)

P(AH) = 0 (since F is down).

I then sum all cases.

-  I believe that for each case, there is no need to specify that the rest are down, since i do not care about them. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: What does it mean for two terminals to be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(AC)=p_B=p$, $P(CH)=p_D=p$ and are assumed independent.

$P(AC$ or $CH$ and not both$) = P(AC)P(\bar{CH})+P(CH)P(\bar{AC}) = 2p(1-p)$

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some more details about the second line of your answer? i am not quite sure I follow.

Comment: You ask for the probability that exactly 2 terminals are connected (not all three). So must insist that if one pair is connected $(p)$, the other is not $(1-p)$. The small bar above the $CH$ means "not" $CH$.

Comment: Thanks. 1) The reason you ignored AH is becuase it is always 0 \ 1, correct? 2) you ignored the states : BE for terminals AC; DG for terminals CH. That is a mistake, correct? I still need to take them into consideration, I believe.

Comment: The state of E is irrelevant for the connection between A and C. B alone determines if A and C are connected (given that F is off). Likewise D alone determines if C and H are connected.